# Need to type special symbol in vi

Tags: vim, vi, symbol-table

I want to type `½` in vi mode but it is coming with extra character `Â½`. I am pressing `ALT+0189`. I have searched a lot on the same but failed to get.

Comment: In vim you can type `<c-k>12`.

Comment: is it  ctrl+k +1+2

Answer (score 3):

If the entry via the terminal doesn't work (it looks like there's an encoding mismatch), you can fall back to Vim's built-in methods for entry of special characters.

## digraphs

A comfortable one is `:help digraphs`. The table at `:help digraph-table` lists that particular character:

```
½   12  0xbd    189 VULGAR FRACTION ONE HALF
```

To insert, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, followed by <kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>2</kbd>.

## entry by number

This is described under `:help i_CTRL-V_digit`. With the decimal number, enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd>. You could also use the hexadecimal representation (`xbd`).

Comment: Hi Ingo, Where do i check "A comfortable one is :help digraphs. The table at :help digraph-table lists that particular character"

Comment: These are links to the built-in help. Just type the `:help digraphs` inside Vim, and hit Enter. A split window with that help topic should open.

Comment: I did the same, nothing happened!!!

Comment: this one i got!

Comment: Oh, your default `vi` is a stripped-down version of Vim. You may need to use / install the full `vim` to get the help.

Comment: i see the line :

Comment: i see the line below line Â½       12      0xbd    189     VULGAR FRACTION ONE HALF. When i am going to edit it with CTRL+K followed by 1 and 2 . Nothing happened.

Comment: With the `:help digraph-table`, I just wanted to show where I've got the `12` from; there are many more digraphs available. To insert (in any buffer, not the help), just press Ctrl-K 1 2 in insert mode.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to type `½` in vi mode but it is coming with extra character `Â½`.

No.

What's happening is that your terminal is sending that character encoded as UTF-8.  The character is U+00BD and its UTF-8 encoding is the two 8-bit character sequence whose hexadecimal values are `C2` `BD`.

vim thinks that you aren't typing in UTF-8, though.  It thinks that you typed two 8-bit characters, first character U+00C2 and then character U+00BD.  Hence it is inserting those two characters.

Making vim believe that you are using UTF-8 is a trip into the complex world of locales and encodings.  vim currently believes that your terminal generates Latin-1 (ISO 8859-1) input.  You need vim to believe that your terminal generates UTF-8 input.

Moreover: It's also apparent, from what is buried in comments to another answer, that your help text isn't being treated as UTF-8 either, indicating that it isn't working internally in UTF-8, probably because your environment variables (`LANG`, `LC_ALL`, and so forth) are not specifying a UTF-8 locale.  In order for vim to properly handle UTF-8 input, it is best for it to be using UTF-8 internally, as its overall encoding.

Something such as the

```
:set termencoding=utf-8 encoding=utf-8
```

command is likely the best course of action.  But you might find yourself adjusting environment variables, too.